# Call wcf from android app

Tags: android, wcf

I have hosted custom wcf service in public URL and calling that wcf from android app its working fine.
 Is it possible to call LAN (Not Public URL) hosted wcf from android. I need to access wcf service from some all the places not only from LAN.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "LAN hosted"? That the service is running on your local pc/server and cannot be accessed from outside? In such case, you wont be able to reach it from other places than you local network. You would have to expose the endpoint to the public (or connect to your network using VPN, but Im not sure whether android is capable of that).

Comment: Thanks Jakub. yes my service hosted in local machine. So now we are hosted that service in public url www.-----.com/Service.svc. In that service i'm accessing db which is installed in my local machine using connection string. but i am unable to acccess that db using from public hosted service                                                                                                                  (Db installed system not reachable) from public hosted service